# Angular.js CRUD Operation

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, crud

I am learning to develop crud orations by using angular js and asp.net MVC. I've currently developed this solution. My Insert function is working correctly but my display data (GetEmployeeById) in text fields doesn't work properly can anyone point me out where I am doing wrong thank you.

My View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            Region
        </th>
        <th>
            Postal Code
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.FirstName" ng-model="employee.FirstName" value="{{employee.FirstName}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.LastName" ng-model="employee.LastName" value="{{employee.LastName}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.Address" ng-model="employee.Address" value="{{employee.Address}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.City" ng-model="employee.City" value="{{employee.City}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.Region" ng-model="employee.Region" value="{{employee.Region}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="employee.PostalCode" ng-model="employee.PostalCode" value="{{employee.PostalCode}}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnSave" ng-click="savedata(employee)" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



<div class="row" >
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Employee ID
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
            <th>
                Region
            </th>
            <th>
                Postal Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Select Employee
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="e in employees">
            <td>{{e.EmployeeID}}</td>
            <td>{{e.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{e.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{e.Address}}</td>
            <td>{{e.City}}</td>
            <td>{{e.Region}}</td>
            <td>{{e.PostalCode}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click="selectEmployee(e.EmployeeID)">Select</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        NorthwindEntities _db=new NorthwindEntities();
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetEmployee()
        {


            return Json(_db.Employees.Select(x=>new
            {
                x.EmployeeID,x.FirstName,x.LastName,x.Address,x.City,x.Region,x.PostalCode
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            _db.Employees.Add(employee);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(_db.Employees.Select(x => new { x.EmployeeID,x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Address, x.City, x.Region, x.PostalCode }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetEmployeeById(int EmployeeID)
        {
            Employee employee = _db.Employees.Find(EmployeeID);
            return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My angular Js app Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('employeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.employees = "";

    $http.get("/Employee/GetEmployee").success(function (result) {
        $scope.employees = result;
    }).error(function(result) {
        console.log("Error");
    });

    $scope.savedata = function (employee) {
        debugger;
        $http.post("/Employee/SaveEmployee", { employee: employee }).success(function (result) {
            debugger;
            $scope.employees = result;
        }).error(function(result) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }

    $scope.employee = "";

    $scope.selectEmployee = function (EmployeeID) {
        debugger;
        $http.post("/Employee/GetEmployeeById/", { EmployeeID: EmployeeID }).success(function (result) {
            debugger;
            $scope.employee = result;
        }).error(function(result) {
            alert(result.message);
        });
}

});
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? It would speculating before we knew that. Does the Java function return anything, does the Ajax call work? Provide a sample return object so we can check that too.

Comment: @PeterS I am getting "undefined" as $scope.selectEmployee goes to error state

Comment: Looking at the code the only way that can happen is if the call is in error and the alert(result.message); result is undefined. If you reduce that to alert(result), does anything happen then? If you console.log(result) in the success block what is shown?

Comment: Hi @PeterS thank you for your valuble time ,i've finally figured out what is the error.

Comment: Please mention what that might be, it could help other stumbling across the same problem.